# If this RESTful API in Flask? Why not?

Tags: python, rest, flask

> A truly RESTful API looks like hypertext. Every addressable unit of
>   information carries an address, either explicitly (e.g., link

https://restfulapi.net

The following code contains the full url. So, it is called RESTful API.

```
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})
```

The following code doesn't contain the full url. So, it is NOT called RESTful API?

```
@app.route("/writeOutput", methods=['POST'])

def writeOutput():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

My question is: What is it called when we use POST but not the full url?

Comment: [https://restfulapi.net/](https://restfulapi.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the *urls* you've posted are *full urls*. They're both paths (uri) in the same application, hence they qualify for being RESTful according to the [specs](https://restfulapi.net/rest-api-design-tutorial-with-example/#model-uris).

However, if you have or are planning to have other versions than `v1.0`, then it is not qualified as a RESTful API as they should be nouns only, i.e. you should write it like `/todo/api/{id}/tasks` this instead.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the url has to do anything with an api being RESTful you read that in detail [here](https://searchapparchitecture.techtarget.com/definition/RESTful-API)

if you call the `/todo/api/v1.0/tasks` with post method it will return you `method not allowed` as the link is only valid for get method.
if you send a request to `/writeOutput` with post method, `def writeOutput():` will be called.